# Архитектура взаимодействия с REST сервисом

Tags: java, rest, архитектура, callback

Дано:

1. REST сервис-калькулятор, который обсчитывает задачи.
2. Конечный сервис, который инициирует расчет задач и обрабатывает результат.

Для расчета задачи вызывается метод этого сервиса. 
Как только задача посчиталась сервис-калькулятор вызывает метод конечного сервиса и передает результат.

Как лучше организовать архитектуру конечного сервиса?

Я придумал следующую схему:

1. Шлем запрос, кладем в ConcurrentHashMap по id задачи объект который содержит запрос/ответ
2. Задача обсчиталась - вызвался метод конечного сервиса
3. По id задачи лезу в мапу, записываю ответ, передаю на обработку
4. Удаляю из мапы

Вроде рабочая схема, но возникает проблема: как удалять задачи, которые не обсчитались за определенное время? Сделать по шедулеру очистку от зависших задач?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя сделать чуть проще? Все запросы на REST обрабатываются в своём потоке. Можно в нём выполнять работу и возвращаешь результат по выполнению. Если не успеваешь, возвращать что там тебе надо, если не успевается. Зачем запоминать id и иметь мапу?

Comment: Но если менять конечный сервис нельзя, то в любом случае можно создавать поток, в нём выполнять всю работу, хранить id запроса, отслеживать время и отправлять результат второму сервису.

Comment: Как раз нельзя менять сервис калькулятор, рассматривается архитектура конечного сервиса.

Comment: Если не хранить в мапе, то как я буду ловить зависшие запросы?

Comment: @BartimeusBartimeus Смотря какая у тебя имплементация расчёта. Если расчёт выполняет какая-то библиотека, которую нельзя остановить в любой момент времени, то просто выполняешь её в ThreadPool как FutureTask. Можно в любой момент её отменить или поставить таймаут на выполнение. Тогда опять же можно всё хранить в потоке запроса. И id тоже.
Если же ты можешь посчитать чуть-чтуь, посмотреть сколько времени прошло, ещё посчитать, ещё посмотреть и т.д., то можно обойтись одним потоком. В нем всё отслеживать. Я бы сделал так. Но можешь и через мапу, если так удобно)

Comment: Расчет происходит на стороне калькулятора. 
Конечный сервис отправил http запрос, все, больше он ничего не делает. Теперь нужно ждать когда калькулятор каллбэк дернет с результатом. 

Футура да, она пришлась к месту, если расчет был на этой стороне.